# C# json deserialization to dictionary (Json.NET)

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

## **Problem**

Hi, help me please to deserialize Json into a C# dictionary, where key of KeyValuePair = value of 'symbol', and 'cur' i don't want to deserialize.

My JSON

```
[
  {
    "cur": "BNT",
    "symbol": "BNT/BTC",
    "last": 0.00069999,
    "high": 0.000725,
    "low": 0.000631,
    "volume": 11.83176914,
    "vwap": 0.00066075,
    "max_bid": 0.000725,
    "min_ask": 0.000631,
    "best_bid": 0.00062001,
    "best_ask": 0.0007
  },
  {
    "cur": "FST",
    "symbol": "FST/BTC",
    "last": 0.00000113,
    "high": 0.00000136,
    "low": 0.0000011,
    "volume": 105727.64821274,
    "vwap": 0.00000115,
    "max_bid": 0.0000012,
    "min_ask": 0.00000108,
    "best_bid": 0.00000115,
    "best_ask": 0.00000127
  }
]
```

C#

```
public class SomeClass
{
    Dictionary<string,Ticker> dictionary { get; set; }
}

public class Ticker
{
    public decimal Last { get; set; }

    public decimal High { get; set; }

    public decimal Low { get; set; }

    public decimal Volume { get; set; }

    public decimal Vwap { get; set; }

    public decimal MaxBid { get; set; }

    public decimal MinAsk { get; set; }

    public decimal BestBid { get; set; }

    public decimal BestAsk { get; set; }
}
```

I think I need to use CustomCreationConverter, but i don't know how to do it :)

Thanks

Comment: You may not need a custom converter.  You do need to read [ask], take the [tour], do more research and ask clearer question

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net Dastun's answer in this thread is what you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I deserialize JSON to a simple Dictionary<string,string> in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json is an array/list. Deserialize to

```
List<Ticker>
```

not to a dictionary.

A more correct model would be

```
public class Ticker
{
    public string cur { get; set; }
    public string symbol { get; set; }
    public double last { get; set; }
    public double high { get; set; }
    public double low { get; set; }
    public double volume { get; set; }
    public double vwap { get; set; }
    public double max_bid { get; set; }
    public double min_ask { get; set; }
    public double best_bid { get; set; }
    public double best_ask { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Ticker>>(jsonstring);
```

If you really need a dictionary

```
var dict = list.ToDictionary(x => x.symbol, x => x);
```

Comment: I think that `symbol` is meant to be the key else they wont know what the data represents...but who knows, its so very poorly asked.

Comment: No, i need to deserialize it in the dictionary. Then I can extract the required pair very easily, for example: Ticker ticker = dict["BTC/USD];

Comment: @N.Kit I also included it in my answer. Read it again (of course it can be done with some json.net tricks like *JsonConverter* but a 2 lines solution is much easier to understand and maintain)

Comment: @Eser sorry, i didn't see :)